# How can i get the number of rows in a ListBox?

Tags: gtk, vala

Don't know if this is the proper place to ask, but i didn't know where else to :p

Answer (score 2):

If you bind the Gtk.ListBox to a model, by means of [`bind_model`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.ListBox.bind_model.html), you then have the GLib.ListModel [`get_n_items`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.ListModel.get_n_items.html) method.

If you didn't then you basically have two ways, keep track of added/removed items or calculate them each time you need the count by means of Gtk.Container [`@foreach`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Container.@foreach.html) method (Gtk.ListBox inherits from Gtk.Container).

To keep track of the count, you could extend/subclass Gtk.ListBox and override the add/remove methods and keep a property/field with the number of children or connect a signal handler to Gtk.Container add/remove signals and keep that same count.

The easiest way, not so efficient, is to use `@foreach` method, which iterates by all children and calculate the number. The count will be done on each method invocation. If this is something you would do many times then it will have some impact.

Here is a very basic example, where we add some Gtk.Label to a Gtk.ListBox and, although we know the number of added labels we will calculate them by clicking the button:

```
using Gtk;

int main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    var window = new Window ();
    window.title = "Vala Listbox Example";
    window.border_width = 10;
    window.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
    window.set_default_size (350, 70);
    window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

    var box = new Gtk.Box (Orientation.VERTICAL, 5);

    var listbox = new ListBox ();

    int i = 10;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        listbox.add (new Label ("A label"));
    }

    var button = new Button.with_label ("Get count!");
    button.clicked.connect (() => {
        int count = 0;
        listbox.@foreach (() => {
            count++;
        });

        print ("Count = %d\n", count);
    });


    box.add (listbox);
    box.add (button);

    window.add (box);

    window.show_all ();

    Gtk.main ();
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose we call this file `main.vala`, compile with:

```
valac main.vala --pkg gtk+-3.0
```

Comment: sadly. error: The name 'foreach' does not exist in the context of `Gtk.ListBox' (gtk4)

Comment: @eexpress The presented example applies to Gtk+ 3. Gtk4 differs. In Gtk4, Gtk.ListBox uses GLib.ListModel and GLib.ListStore implements that interface. Therefore you can use ListModel get_n_items method or ListStore n_items property. The code above was just an workaround available in Gtk+3 and in fact, non desirable. Why iterate the model and count when we have the value available in one step  ;).

Comment: I meet a issue. I can't use `listbox.remove_all` method because this only works on special glib version and above. I test select_all then select.foreach to remove, but it crash. So I need get the length, remove manully from n-1 to 0 by index.

Comment: Hi @eexpress you should open a new question with a MVCE to address your specific case. Also mention versions used when doing it, so people can track your claims. GL

Answer (score 1):

In Python, it would be `len(listbox)`. In other words, just get the length of the listbox.

Comment: Well that looks too easy. By chance yo know how to do the same in vala? I have searched, but i couldn't find an attribute or method.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in C.

```
gint index = 0;
while ( gtk_list_box_get_row_at_index (widget,index++) != NULL ) {
g_print("%d\n",index);
}
```